# Most representative document in a list of documents

Tags: python, nlp, document, tf-idf

Hi I am trying to find out what the most representative document in a list of documents might be. I am wondering if there are any resources or documentation on being able to do that. I have put together some simple statistics that help me do this:

- Removing stop words, using bigrams
- Matrix multiply and sum of TF multiplied by DF to get a score for the document
- Whatever document has a TF*DF Score closest to average TF * DF will be retrieved

So the idea is that the higher the DF is, the more representative it is of the corpus. If TF scoring is optimized for the average, so documents that overuse or underuse a high DF word are punished.

It's pretty hacky but wondering if there is something better out there that people have encountered.

Answer (score 0):

Are you correctly referring to DF? or do you mean Inverse Document Frequency? Cause in order to introduce the penalization you need to use the inverse. I recently implemented some tools for this using dictionaries for faster results.

You need three of them:

```
token_doc_count = { doc_id: {token_id: count}}
tokens_freq_corpus = {token_id: count}
tokened_docs = {doc_id: list_of_tokens or string_of_tokens}
```

Also, TF - IDF should penalize stop words so it's not necessary to remove them.

Comment: well IDF will penalize important topical words in the corpus-- so in a corpus about trump, 90% of them mention immigration, while 10% talk mention the environment. IDF will penalize "immigration" even though it is more representative